# DropDownList has duplicate values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My dropdownlist has duplicate values being the item_brand. How can remove the duplicates? Have tried using distinct. Basically the user must select the item brand then a list of items will populate based on that brand. But if I have two products with the same brand that brand name will populate twice in the brandList

My view

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm(new { OrderID = Model.OrderID }))
   {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Item Information</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            <section class="panel">


                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedBrand, "Brand", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBrand,Model.BrandList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SelectedBrand, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                            </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedItem, "Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.ItemList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedItem, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item_order_quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item_order_quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item_order_quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.OrderID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>


                    </div>
            </section>
        </div>


                <section class="panel">

                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <input type="submit" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;" />
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Order", new { id = Model.OrderID }, null)" class="btn btn-info"> Back</a>

                    </div>
                </section>



    <!-- JS includes -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var itemUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchItems")';
            var items = $('#SelectedItem');

            $('#SelectedBrand').change(function() {
                items.empty();

                $.getJSON(itemUrl, { brand: $(this).val()},function(data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        return ;
                    }
                    items.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));

                    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        items.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                    });
                });

            })


    </script>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
// GET: ItemOrder/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int ID)
    {
        ORDER order = db.Order.Find(ID);
        ItemOrderVM model = new ItemOrderVM() { 
        OrderID = order.OrderID
        };

        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);




    }
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FetchItems(int brand)
    {
        var data = db.Item.Where(l => l.ItemID == (brand))
            .Select(l => new { Value = l.ItemID, Text = l.item_description });

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    private void ConfigureViewModel(ItemOrderVM model)
    {
        var brand = (from m in db.Item
                        select m);

        model.BrandList = new SelectList(db.Item, "ItemID", "item_brand");

       if (model.SelectedBrand.HasValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<ITEM> items = db.Item.Where(l => l.item_brand.Equals(model.SelectedBrand));
            model.ItemList = new SelectList(items, "ItemID", "item_description");
        }
        else
        {
            model.ItemList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
        }

    }
```

ItemOrder View Model

```
public class ItemOrderVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Quantity")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be greater than 0")]
    public int item_order_quantity { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    public int ? SelectedBrand { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
     public SelectList BrandList { get; set; }
     public SelectList ItemList { get; set; }
     public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You can have an extra property like Category.

Comment: You need to stop doing code dumps and post only the relevant code. Almost all this is irrelevant and the important part (the data model for `ITEM`) is missing. You need to use `.Distinct()` on your query and pass it a comparer (refer [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx) for an example) but your fundamental problem as I noted in one of your previous questions is that you database structure is wrong. You need a separate table for `Brands`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `model.BrandList` since you are selecting `ItemId` which I assume is unique so you have the same `item_brand` that appears multiple times

So all you need is to get a list of distinct brands.
In your `ConfigureViewModel` method:

```
model.BrandList = db.Item.Select(i => new SelectListItem{Text = i.item_brand, Value = i.item_brand}).Distrinct().ToList();
```

(If you have an `item_brand_id` property that is unique for each brend you should use it as value)

And then in your Fetch action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FetchItems(string brand)
{
    var data = db.Item.Where(l => l.item_brand == brand)
        .Select(l => new { Value = l.ItemID, Text = l.item_description });

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: At model.brandList Im getting this error: Error 15 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Comment: Ok I removed the error but still getting duplicate values